# Hello. I'm building an app and I'm trying to avoid my onboarding screen showing at every startup. I want it to show only once per user

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my main.dart file:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    configOneSignal();
  }

  void configOneSignal() {
    OneSignal.shared.init(kAppID);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
      create: (_) => ThemeChanger(),
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        final themeChanger = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: TITLE,
          themeMode: themeChanger.getTheme,
          darkTheme: Style.get(true),
          theme: Style.get(false),
          home: Directionality(
            textDirection: textDirection,
            child: OnboardingScreenOne(),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

I need help making sure that my splash screen doesnt come up to every user on every startup. So I want to have it show only once per user per device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package to store a isFirstTime boolean variable. Set it to true in the beginning. When the user finishes the onboarding for the first time, set it to false. And when loading the app, you can check if isFirstTime is true; if it is true, show onboarding, otherwise skip to home.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to record user behavior, once the user navigator after onboarding pages, record it locally, then determine by retrieving the value back when open app:

```
      home: Directionality(
        textDirection: textDirection,
        child: isRead? HomePage() : OnboardingScreenOne(),
```